# culture folder is not created during compilation using satellite assembly

Tags: asp.net, localization, satellite-assembly

I am working on satellite assembly.In future we need to use resource "DLL" instead of .Resx file of all culture.everything is fine but when i am compile the project using batch,few culture folder is not created inside obj\debug.
please see in below where only fr-FR and gu-IN folder is created.why pa_IN folder is not created?
i did not understand why this problem is occurred
.please guide or suggest me,what should i have to do?i need to improve code or need extra setting?
below is my compile code:

```
Microsoft (R) Build Engine Version 4.0.30319.1
[Microsoft .NET Framework, Version 4.0.30319.296]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2007. All rights reserved.

Build started 9/12/2013 3:24:35 PM.
Project "D:\MyProject\DynamicResourceDLL.csproj" on node 1 (rebuild target(s)).
CoreClean:
  Deleting file "D:\MyProject\bin\Debug\makeDll.dll".
  Deleting file "D:\MyProject\bin\Debug\makeDll.pdb".
  Deleting file "D:\MyProject\obj\Debug\makeDll.dll".
  Deleting file "D:\MyProject\obj\Debug\makeDll.pdb".
CoreResGen:
  "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\resgen.exe" /useSourcePath /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\Microsoft.CSharp.dll" /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\mscorlib.dll" /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Core.dll" /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Data.dll" /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.dll" /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Xml.dll" /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /compile Circle\Oval5\Oval5.resx,obj\Debug\makeDll.Circle.Oval5.Oval5.resources Circle\Oval5\Oval5.pa_IN.resx,obj\Debug\makeDll.Circle.Oval5.Oval5.pa_IN.resources Circle\Oval5\Oval5.fr-FR.resx,obj\Debug\makeDll.Circle.Oval5.Oval5.fr-FR.resources Circle\Oval5\Oval5.gu-IN.resx,obj\Debug\makeDll.Circle.Oval5.Oval5.gu-IN.resources
  Processing resource file "Circle\Oval5\Oval5.resx" into "obj\Debug\makeDll.Circle.Oval5.Oval5.resources".
  Processing resource file "Circle\Oval5\Oval5.pa_IN.resx" into "obj\Debug\makeDll.Circle.Oval5.Oval5.pa_IN.resources".
  Processing resource file "Circle\Oval5\Oval5.fr-FR.resx" into "obj\Debug\makeDll.Circle.Oval5.Oval5.fr-FR.resources".
  Processing resource file "Circle\Oval5\Oval5.gu-IN.resx" into "obj\Debug\makeDll.Circle.Oval5.Oval5.gu-IN.resources".
GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
CoreCompile:
  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702 /nostdlib+ /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:DEBUG;TRACE /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\Microsoft.CSharp.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\mscorlib.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Core.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Data.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Xml.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /debug+ /debug:full /filealign:512 /optimize- /out:obj\Debug\makeDll.dll /resource:obj\Debug\makeDll.Circle.Oval5.Oval5.resources /resource:obj\Debug\makeDll.Circle.Oval5.Oval5.pa_IN.resources /target:library Circle\Oval5\Oval5.Designer.cs Circle\Oval5\Oval5.Designer.pa_IN.cs Circle\Oval5\Oval5.Designer.fr-FR.cs Circle\Oval5\Oval5.Designer.gu-IN.cs Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs "C:\Users\schakravorty\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.0.AssemblyAttributes.cs"
GenerateSatelliteAssemblies:
  Creating directory "obj\Debug\fr-FR".
  Creating directory "obj\Debug\gu-IN".
  c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\AL.exe /culture:fr-FR /out:obj\Debug\fr-FR\makeDll.resources.dll /template:obj\Debug\makeDll.dll /embed:obj\Debug\makeDll.Circle.Oval5.Oval5.fr-FR.resources
GenerateSatelliteAssemblies:
  c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\AL.exe /culture:gu-IN /out:obj\Debug\gu-IN\makeDll.resources.dll /template:obj\Debug\makeDll.dll /embed:obj\Debug\makeDll.Circle.Oval5.Oval5.gu-IN.resources
CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
  Copying file from "obj\Debug\makeDll.dll" to "bin\Debug\makeDll.dll".
  makeDll -> D:\MyProject\bin\Debug\makeDll.dll
  Copying file from "obj\Debug\makeDll.pdb" to "bin\Debug\makeDll.pdb".
  Creating directory "bin\Debug\fr-FR".
  Copying file from "obj\Debug\fr-FR\makeDll.resources.dll" to "bin\Debug\fr-FR\makeDll.resources.dll".
  Creating directory "bin\Debug\gu-IN".
  Copying file from "obj\Debug\gu-IN\makeDll.resources.dll" to "bin\Debug\gu-IN\makeDll.resources.dll".
Done Building Project "D:\MyProject\makeDll.csproj" (rebuild target(s)).

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:01.09
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the resource filename from pa_IN to pa.IN

From [MSDN][1]

> The culture name in the format languagecode2-country/regioncode2.
>   languagecode2 is a lowercase two-letter code derived from ISO 639-1.
>   country/regioncode2 is derived from ISO 3166 and usually consists of
>   two uppercase letters.

[1] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.name.aspx